# Can KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry be used for re-uploading all the clients configs?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Can I call stop() on the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry and after that start() to reload all the kafka client configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes.
But I would suggest to just do a pause and resume instead of start and stop. Because if you are working with multiple partitions then stop/start will trigger rebalancing of consumers while pause/resume maintain the original config i.e. consumer will consume from same partition as before